# not sure what to use rebase or merge?

Tags: git, merge, rebase, git-rebase, git-remote

I was accidently using the gh-pages branch so now it has become the most updated one. How can I bring the master branch up to date if it hasn't been used?
 I think the proper diagram is this

```
        / E-F-G
A-B-C-D
```

How would I go about this? when ever I've tried I always mess it up

A-B-C-D-E...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the diagram is correct, you don't need to rebase.

If you merge, git will perform a fast-forward merge, giving you:

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-G
```

So:

```
git checkout master
git merge gh-pages
```

Comment: See: [an explanation of fast-forward merges](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Branching) in Pro Git.